# Calling Modal section in thymeleaf based on another field

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using spring boot with thymeleaf as frontend. I have a requirement to NOT call a modal if one of the drop down option is selected. The form is as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div th:replace="navigation :: nav_bar"></div>
        <div class="col">
            <form th:object="${answeredQuestionnaire}" method="post">
                <h1>[[#{nav.bcmDecisionCriteria}]]</h1>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div th:each="role: ${loggedInUser.applicationUserRoles}">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        
                            <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-4  text-left pt-2">
                                        <label class="form-group font-weight-bold"> [[#{review.differentBCMClass}]] :</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div  class="form-group col-2  text-left pt-2">
                                        <select th:field="*{classOverridden}" name="classOverridden">
                                            <option value=""  default >[[#{pleaseSelect}]]</option>
                                            <option class="text-center" th:value="1"  >1</option>
                                            <option class="text-center" th:value="2"   >2</option>
                                            <option class="text-center" th:value="3"   >3</option>
                                            <option class="text-center" th:value="4" >4</option>
                                            <option class="text-center" th:value="0" >0</option>
    
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-6 ">
                            <label class="font-weight-bold "> [[#{review.commentForDifferentClass}]] : </label>
                            <textarea rows="5"
                                      th:placeholder="#{comment}"
                                      th:field="*{classOverriddenComment}"
                                      th:value="${answeredQuestionnaire.classOverriddenComment}"
                                      th:text="${answeredQuestionnaire.classOverriddenComment}"
                                      class="form-control"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
    
    
                    
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group form-row text-center"
                         th:if="${role.roleName != 'Manager' and role.roleName != 'Officer' }">
                        
                        <div class="form-group col  text-center pt-2"  >
                            <button type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-info btn-block " role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#managerSelectForCooridnator">
                                [[#{review.submit}]]
                            </button>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>


<div class="form-group form-row text-center">

                    <div class="form-group col  text-center pt-2"  >
                        <button type="button"
                                class="btn btn-info btn-block " role="button"  formaction="/someOtherURL">
                            [[#{review.submit}]]
                        </button>

                    </div>
                </div>
                    
    
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this form if **classOverridden** is selected with any option then the model with id **#managerSelectForCooridnator** is NOT called.
How to implement this using js. Any sample code will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would probably be to add an event listener to the select and then remove the data-target and data-toggle properties from the submit button.

First you probably should add ids to the select and the button, just to make it easier to access them:

```
<select th:field="*{classOverridden}" id="classOverriddenSelect" name="classOverridden">

<button type="button" id ="submitButton "class="btn btn-info btn-block " role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#managerSelectForCooridnator">
```

Then you can add the event listener to the select and remove the attributes, if the value of the select isn't the default (and of course add it again, if it is default, assuming it is possible to reselect the default).

```
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton')
const select = document.getElementById('classOverriddenSelect')
select .addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (select.value != '') {        
        submitButton.removeAttribute('data-toggle')
        submitButton.removeAttribute('data-target')
    } else {
        submitButton.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal')
        submitButton.setAttribute('data-target', '#managerSelectForCooridnator')
    }
})
```

Comment: I am completely new to js, could you please mention which attribute I need on select, and how to use the js code mentioned.

Comment: Change the select and button HTML as it is shown in the answer and then add the js to the HTML file or js file, if you have one.